# Passing arguments to Access Forms created with 'New'

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have a form called 'detail' which shows a detailed view of a selected record.  The record is selected from a different form called 'search'.  Because I want to be able to open multiple instances of 'detail', each showing details of a different record, I used the following code:

```
Public detailCollection As New Collection    

Function openDetail(patID As Integer, pName As String)
'Purpose:    Open an independent instance of form
Dim frm As Form
Debug.Print "ID: " & patID

'Open a new instance, show it, and set a caption.
Set frm = New Form_detail
frm.Visible = True
frm.Caption = pName


detailCollection.Add Item:=frm, Key:=CStr(frm.Hwnd)

Set frm = Nothing
End Function
```

PatID is the Primary Key of the record I wish to show in this new instance of 'detail.'  The debug print line prints out the correct PatID, so i have it available.  How do I pass it to this new instance of the form?

I tried to set the OpenArgs of the new form, but I get an error stating that OpenArgs is read only.  After researching, OpenArgs can only be set by DoCmd (which won't work, because then I don't get independent instances of the form).  I can find no documentation on the allowable parameters when creating a Form object.  Apparently, Microsoft doesn't consider a Constructor to be a Method, at least according to the docs.  How should I handle this? (plz don't tell me to set it to an invisible text box or something) Thanks guys, you guys are the best on the net at answering these questions for me.  I love you all!

Source Code for the multi-instance form taken from: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-35.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside your Form_detail, create a custom property.

```
Private mItemId As Long

Property Let ItemID(value as Long)
    mItemId = value
    ' some code to re query Me
End Property

Property Get ItemId() As Long
    ItemId = mItemId
End Property
```

Then, in the code that creates the form, you can do this.

```
Set frm = New Form_detail

frm.ItemId = patId

frm.Visible = True
frm.Caption = pName
```

This will allow you to pass an ID to the new form instance, and ensure it gets requeried before making it visible. No need to load all of the results every time if you're always opening the form by `New`ing it. You let the property load the data instead of the traditional `Form_Load` event.

This works because Access Form modules are nothing more than glorified classes. Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice.  I had no clue such a thing as 'property' even existed.  With all the googling I did, you think it would have poped up at some point.  I already implemented the solution by setting the record source, but then I had a problem figuring out if a particular detail was already open.  This should fix that problem for me.  Also, there were some other problems with the record source option, such as using the patID to load data from other tables in the detail view.  Was having to set those from the same place as the form recordsource. Thank you RubberDuck.

Comment: You're very welcome! I'm happy I could help. I highly recommend [CPearson's article about classes in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx). It should help clear up any questions you have about why this works.

Comment: Thanks RubberDuck that was helpful.  As someone who learned OOP from Java/Python, I find VBA ... odd.  I know the algorithms I want, and yet I am googling EVERY little thing I want to do.  It's getting annoying.  All the info I can get is useful, and Microsoft doesn't make it easy to find.

Comment: I don't want to get too chatty, but [I've been collecting useful links on my blog](http://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/links/). Might be some stuff worth bookmarking. There's also [Code Review's vba chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba).

Comment: TY.  I will check those out. I need the help.  Anything before resorting to MSDN. =)

Comment: A lot of those links are to MSDN. =)
It should be your first resource. Although, I can agree that their documents could be better.

Answer (score 3):

You could try applying a filter:

```
frm.Filter = "[ID] = " & patID
frm.FilterOn = True
```

The Record Source of the Detail form will need to be set to the table to which the ID belongs.

UPDATE
As you requested, here is the code to set the RecordSource:

```
frm.RecordSource = "select * from TableName where [ID] = " & patID
```

This is probably cleaner than using a filter given that a user can remove the filter (depending on the type of form).

Comment: I wish I knew enough about VB to know if this will work.  Ill have to try it out and see.  I would like to query the BE to return a single record only, so as to lighten the load in a multi-user environment.  I shall investigate this tonight.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I was just thinking about the record source.  If you set the recordSource to a query string, the data will be there.  That's probably all I needed to do.  If you add a couple lines of code to your answer that sets the recordsource to a table with a filter, as well as to a query that returns a single record from table based on patID, your answer will be complete for the next guy and I shall green check mark you.  =)  If not I'll do it later and still check mark you.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was just thinking that the recordSource property would be set via the GUI, that is unless that needs to be dynamic as well.

Comment: Sorry Fungus, your solution worked pretty well, but it had some issues.  RubberDuck's answer ends up working better and has other possible applications for people who want to do other stuff then pick the record.  Gonna have to green check him.  Thanks for your help Fungus, appreciate it.